# All my threads are waiting in my WebScraper project. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiler

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so please go easy on me! I made this Web Scraper as a final project in my CS course last semester. I was able to pass with it, however, it always bothered me about how slow my program ran compared to others in the class. My program took 11 hours to gather 10,000 emails, whereas my friend took 5 minutes. I couldn't figure out why! I even tried seeing what's wrong with a java profiler, and it just showed me that my threads are waiting. I don't know how to fix that and why it only affected me. I really want to learn about how to properly use threads, so I'm asking you guys.

My CPU is an i7 7700k, so there shouldn't be a problem there and I have Gigabit internet. So it's definitely the way I coded my program. Here is the main class:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    static int EMAIL_MAX_COUNT = 10_000;
    static int MAX_VISITS = 5;
    static final Set<String> emails = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>(10_000));
    static Set<String> linksToVisit = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>(20_000));
    static Set<String> linksFilter = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>(20_000));
    static Set<String> linksVisited = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>(10_000));
    static Map<String, Set<String>> maxLinksVisited = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
        linksToVisit.add("https://www.touro.edu/");//starts with touro.edu

        while (!linksToVisit.isEmpty() && emails.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {
            String link;
            synchronized (linksToVisit) {
                link = linksToVisit.stream().findFirst().get();
                System.out.println(link);
                linksToVisit.remove(link);
            }
            if (hasTooManyVisits(link)) {
                link = "";
            }
            if (!(link.equals(""))) {
                linksVisited.add(link);
                pool.execute(new WebScraper(link));
            }
        }
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static boolean hasTooManyVisits(String link) {
        try {
            URL currentURL = new URL(link);
            String host = currentURL.getHost();

            int startIndex = 0;
            int nextIndex = host.indexOf('.');
            int lastIndex = host.lastIndexOf('.');
            while (nextIndex < lastIndex) {
                startIndex = nextIndex + 1;
                nextIndex = host.indexOf('.', startIndex);
            }
            synchronized (maxLinksVisited) {
                if (startIndex > 0) {
                    Set<String> tempSet = maxLinksVisited.get(host.substring(startIndex));
                    if (tempSet == null) {
                        tempSet = new HashSet<>();
                        maxLinksVisited.put(host.substring(startIndex), tempSet);
                    }
                    tempSet.add(link);
                    maxLinksVisited.put(host.substring(startIndex), tempSet);
                    if (maxLinksVisited.get(host.substring(startIndex)).size() >= MAX_VISITS) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Set<String> tempSet = maxLinksVisited.get(host);
                    if (tempSet == null) {
                        tempSet = new HashSet<>();
                        maxLinksVisited.put(host, tempSet);
                    }
                    tempSet.add(link);
                    maxLinksVisited.put(host, tempSet);
                    if (maxLinksVisited.get(host).size() >= MAX_VISITS) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

All it really does is setup the initial part of the program and create the threads. Here is the WebScraper class:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WebScraper implements Runnable {

    String currentUrl;
    String[] randomFileExtensions = {"png", "jpg", "gif", "pdf", "mp3", "css", "mp4", "mov", "7z", "zip", "mkv", "avi", "jpeg"};//common files

    WebScraper(String url) {
        this.currentUrl = url;
        run();//for some reason it's needed
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try { // double try block so the program doesn't stop on errors
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(currentUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();

                Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d._]+@[\\w\\d]+\\.[\\w]{2,3}");
                Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(doc.toString());

                while (emailMatcher.find()) {//find and add emails
                    String email = emailMatcher.group();
                    if (Arrays.stream(randomFileExtensions).parallel().noneMatch(email::contains)) {//filter for any files that are not emails
                        Main.emails.add(emailMatcher.group());
                    }
                }
                synchronized (Main.linksFilter) {
                    Main.linksFilter.addAll(doc.select("a[href]").eachAttr("abs:href"));//find and add all links on the page
                    for (String randomFileExtension : randomFileExtensions) {
                        Main.linksFilter.removeIf(s -> s.contains(randomFileExtension));//filter links for any files
                    }
                    synchronized (Main.linksToVisit) {
                        Main.linksFilter.removeAll(Main.linksVisited);
                        Main.linksToVisit.addAll(Main.linksFilter);
                        Main.linksFilter.clear();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

One thing that bothers me is that the program will stop after touro.edu if I take out the run(); method from the constructor. I don't know why, the program should automatically call it...

In conclusion, I just want to know what I did wrong. Please help me understand, and thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

first, you can't call the `pool.shutdownNow();` method, suggest call `pool.shutdown();`
they are different can read the java document.
when you call `java.util.Collections#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set<T>)` method, the return Set is already thread-safe, so you don't add `synchronized`.